# Unity error: Error launching the editor. The application path ..../MacOS/Unity does not exist

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a new user of Unity, and I'm trying to work on the Karting Microgame project from the Learn tab in Unity Hub. When I try to open the project, however, the error "Error launching the editor. The application path ....Contents/MacOS/Unity does not exist" appears. When I look into the MacOS folder in my terminal, I don't see the Unity folder. Where did it go?

Comment: Do you see any Unity versions under `Installs` in Unity Hub? Did you install it firsthand, or you just downloaded a learning project?

Comment: I installed it firsthand